# Wpf- Apply colour to particular cell in data grid

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am  trying to apply color to particular cell of data grid. I did some research but ended up in changing color of entire row instead of what I wanted.

My requirement is this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a `CellStyle` for the particular column:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="..." Binding="{Binding Name}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

You could use `DataTriggers` to apply the foreground conditionally:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Name}" Value="30">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Since there are no `<` and `>` operators defined in XAML, you will have to use a converter to be able to set the `Foreground` if the value is less than or greater than some value.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want interest xaml , this code maybe work for yor need. (xx ,yy is row and colonm number)

DataGridCell cell =(YourDgName.Columns[XX].GetCellContent(DgCagrilar.Items[YY])).Parent s DataGridCell; if (cell.Background == Brushes.Pink) cell.Background = Brushes.Plum; else cell.Background = Brushes.Pink;